# How to use ternary operator in spring security XML config to pass role

Tags: java, spring-security

I would like to evaluate whether I should apply security or not on particular URL.

I tried below ways but no luck.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" 
      access="'${monitor.status}' == 'secured' ? 'ROLE_FIND' : permitAll"/>  

<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" 
    access="'${monitor.status}' == 'secured' ? ROLE_FIND : permitAll"/>  

<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring"
    access="'${monitor.status}' == 'secured' ? 'ROLE_FIND' : 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'"/>
```

No luck with these. What is correct syntax for this. I can not use expression based. Please suggest me in this style only.

All of the above saying that `access denied`, even right permission is there. I am not sure whether it is because of this or other configuration in my project.

EDIT: `${monitor.status}` is coming from property file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it using [SpEL][1] like

```
<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="#{'${monitor.status}' == 'secured' ? 'ROLE' : 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'}"/>
```

Comment: Could you give me correct syntax, where double quotes are closing where  `{` are closing.

Comment: closing `"` is missing at `}`

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, Yesterday syntax is working after doing small corrections(missing `''` around property(`${monitor.status}`) and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`). `<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="#{'${monitor.status}' == 'secured' ? 'ROLE' : 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'}"/>`

Comment: Great! I have reverted back to my original answer with this correction.